# How to skip double space in a space delimited .txt in R?

Tags: r, import, na, raw-data

The problem is that I have multiple raw data, in multiple .txt, with data like this in every file:

```
 -7.400513E-02  1.424561E-04 
 -.0592041  1.426086E-04 
 -4.440308E-02  1.436768E-04 
 -2.960205E-02  1.452942E-04 
 -1.480103E-02  1.473999E-04 
  0  1.499939E-04 
  1.480103E-02  1.531982E-04 
  2.960205E-02  1.567383E-04 
  4.440308E-02  1.603394E-04 
  .0592041  1.636658E-04
```

I'm importing and mixing all this data, so I can work with it, with the next code:

```
Listoffiles <- list.files(pattern = "txt")
Listofdata <- map(Listadearchivos, ~vroom(.x, delim = " ",
                                          col_names = FALSE, 
                                          col_types = c(.default = "n")))
Data1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, Listofdata)
```

The problem is that I'm getting a mixed data.frame with NA, because in the raw data there are columns for the sign of the number, spaces for + and - for -, and many double spaces as delimiter, giving me a result like this:

```
    
 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   NA  -0.08880615 NA  0.0001429749    NA
2   NA  -0.07400513 NA  0.0001424561    NA
3   NA  -0.05920410 NA  0.0001426086    NA
4   NA  -0.04440308 NA  0.0001436768    NA
5   NA  -0.02960205 NA  0.0001452942    NA
6   NA  -0.01480103 NA  0.0001473999    NA
7   NA  NA  0.00000000  NA  0.0001499939
8   NA  NA  0.01480103  NA  0.0001531982
9   NA  NA  0.02960205  NA  0.0001567383
10  NA  NA  0.04440308  NA  0.0001603394
11  NA  NA  0.05920410  NA  1.6366580000
```

What can I do in order to get only the two columns with the values?

Comment: If you are okay with post-import cleanup, you should be able to remove the NA's and collapse to two columns after the fact with something like: `t(apply(your_dataframe, 1, na.exclude))`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns thank for your response, i'm okay with the solution you proposed, and probably I will you use it, but still I think that the answer from CSJCampbell is a better answer to my question than yours (maybe not the best to my problem). Thanks you for the fast answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**data.table**'s `fread` parses your data correctly.

```
library(data.table)
Data1 <- fread("test-file.txt")
Data1
#              V1           V2
#  1: -0.07400513 0.0001424561
#  2: -0.05920410 0.0001426086
#  3: -0.04440308 0.0001436768
#  4: -0.02960205 0.0001452942
#  5: -0.01480103 0.0001473999
#  6:  0.00000000 0.0001499939
#  7:  0.01480103 0.0001531982
#  8:  0.02960205 0.0001567383
#  9:  0.04440308 0.0001603394
# 10:  0.05920410 0.0001636658
```

You can then collapse the list of data.tables to a single table using `data.table::rbindlist`.

```
Listadearchivos <- list.files(pattern = "txt")
Listofdata <- map(Listadearchivos, ~fread(.x))
Data1 <- as.data.frame(rbindlist(Listofdata))
Data1
#             V1           V2
# 1  -0.07400513 0.0001424561
# 2  -0.05920410 0.0001426086
# 3  -0.04440308 0.0001436768
# 4  -0.02960205 0.0001452942
# 5  -0.01480103 0.0001473999
# 6   0.00000000 0.0001499939
# 7   0.01480103 0.0001531982
# 8   0.02960205 0.0001567383
# 9   0.04440308 0.0001603394
# 10  0.05920410 0.0001636658
```

Comment: Thanks @CSJcampbell for your answer, it work well for me, I'm still learning and I'm used to data.frame more than tibbles and data.table, maybe its time for me to learn how to use it.

Comment: @AlGiRe thought you were in **tidyverse** :-) switched to data.frame